# understanding why swift code won't work correctly

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm new to coding and currently teaching myself swift using swift playgrounds on the iPad. My code runs and completes the puzzle but it continues to loop and I don't know why.  I can't find any way to correct this code. Although I have found videos on YouTube with various code written differently. I don't just want to copy it though. I want to understand why this isn't working. I can send a video of the puzzle if needed.

```
while !isOnGem || !isOnClosedSwitch  {
    moveForward()
    if isBlocked && !isBlockedRight {
        turnRight()

    }
    if isBlocked && isBlockedRight {
        turnLeft()
    }
    if isOnGem {
        collectGem()
    }
    if isOnClosedSwitch {
        toggleSwitch()
    }

}
```

Comment: have you change the `isOnGem ` and `isOnClosedSwitch ` value?

Comment: Please, how can anyone be expected to answer this? You don't give us enough. We get the issue - looping continues, probably due to isOnGem and isOnClosedSwitch always being true - but from what little code you've given us it appears (please, this isn't necessarily the answer) that turnRight(), turnLeft(), collectGem(), or toggleSwitch() isn't setting the loop check the way you want. Could you post some extra code?

Comment: Dfd there is no extra code to add. I just needed it to stop looping. But it was answered for me. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **exit condition**. `while !isOnGem || !isOnClosedSwitch`will continue to loop as long as **either** condition is `true`, therefore your exit condition will be having both values set to `false`.

Note that both Booleans are inverted in your check so to make both conditions `false` you have to set the Booleans to `true`.

Since you code runs and yet does not exit to loop, you will want to check for changes to `isOnGem` and `isOnClosedSwitch` there might be one of the two that is always `false` resulting in the loop not exiting or the function that runs after each checks might have reset them to `false`

check for code like:

```
func collectGem(){
    ...
    isOnGem = false
    ...
}
```

or one of the functions might not even have run, you can log each function like :

```
func toggleSwitch() {
    print("toggleSwitchRunning")
}
```

and if "toggleSwitchRunning" did not print into the console, check that the condition that set `isOnClosedSwitch` to `true` is working properly

Comment: Thank you Ben. Will make changes.

Comment: Thank you Jason. This feedback really helps. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CashmereTatum if you need more basic info, SO have a [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics) page that have much useful info. Also [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) own documentation for swift might help too

Answer (score 1):

Without any other information regarding the functions in each of your `if` blocks, I'd say that it is due to your boolean values for `isOnGem` and `isOnClosedSwitch`. If the function `collectGem()` does not change the value of `isOnGem` to the opposite of what it was initially set to (true or false) and `toggleSwitch()` doesn't change the value of `isOnClosedSwitch` to the opposite of it's original value then you will be stuck in the loop. Since the loop will run "while" at least one of those values remain unchanged.

I believe adding a `isOnGem = false` and `isOnClosedSwitch = false` to their respective `if` blocks will be the solution.

Comment: Thank u both for answering this helps.